# RoR datatable never loads data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

This is my first time using dataTables. I want to be able to display the records in my Projects table and sort by each field. I'm following this RailCast and used the code provided by them. However, my page loads without errors but the actual records are never loaded into the table--it just says "Processing..." indefinitely. Any ideas what would cause this? Some of my code:

view/projects/new.html.erb (where the index of my application points to, and where I want the table displayed)

```
<table id="projects" class="display" data-source="<%= projects_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

projects.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("#projects").dataTable
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#projects').data('source')
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
```

projects controller

```
  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.json
  def new
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: ProjectsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
```

Projects_datatable.rb

```
class ProjectsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view   
  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Project.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: Project.count,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    projects.map do |proj|
      [
        h(proj.filename),
        h(proj.author)
      ]
    end
  end

  def projects
    @projects ||= fetch_projects
  end

  def fetch_projects
    projects = Project.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    projects = projects.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      projects = projects.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    projects
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[name category released_on price]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

And my projects migration:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :filename
      t.string :location
      t.string :author
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone has any input I'd be so grateful. thanks.

Comment: I must admit that you're following Skinny Controller Fat Model conception very well, but this code is 'smells'. I love the way you hidden all scary stuff into model, but you can't create all project just with hacking. You've created special model for just this small task and you absolutely can't base all your behavior at `view_context` since it's named that way for a reason. Also dataTables creates naming conventions chaos. Maybe you should try [poirot](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is certainly a bit late but i can see some mistakes at those lines :

```
projects = projects.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```

and

```
columns = %w[name category released_on price]
```

You have to replace those fields by filename, location, author.

```
iTotalDisplayRecords:  Project.count,
```

is also wrong, replace it with

```
iTotalDisplayRecords: projects.total_entries,
```

Be sure that you have will_paginate